# iTextSharp - take image from PictureBox control and insert it into a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I'm looking to take an image from a picturebox control and insert it into my PDF document. I can write the PDF document fine and have found information on inserting an image from file or resources but cannot find anything for use with a picturebox.
the below code will work from a file but how would I pickup an image from a picture box? or would I need to save the image as a temp file first?

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath);
image.ScalePercent(24f);
doc.Add(image);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an image from `MemoryStream`

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    Image img = Image.GetInstance(ms);
```

Or you can use byte array

```
    byte[] bytes = GetImageBytesSomehow();
    Image img = Image.GetInstance(bytes);
```

**Update (Bruno Lowagie)**:

I've found the following question on MSDN: [Read image from picturebox and store it in byte array](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8723a391-20f1-4249-a49c-07a1ceb11a62/read-image-from-picturebox-and-store-it-in-byte-array?forum=winforms)

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] buff = ms.GetBuffer();
```

Now you can create an `Image` instance with `buff` as parameter.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what is meant by picture box, but as Aleksandr indicates, you don't need a path to a physical image file on disk if you have the image as a `byte[]`. You have to look at the object that is described as a "picture box" and find out how to implement the `GetImageBytesSomehow()` method.

Comment: PcitureBox is a Windows Forms control. Ok thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I've found some code here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8723a391-20f1-4249-a49c-07a1ceb11a62/read-image-from-picturebox-and-store-it-in-byte-array?forum=winforms I'll update Aleksandr's answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie feel free to do it. My point was that every control should have an export as stream or bytes array. So using code above he should be able to pass it to a pdf